# How can I configure RedisInsight Proxy Path in Kubernetes with Nginx ingress?

Tags: redis, redisinsights

I am seeking help to get the URL path to work in redisinsight

as per documentation i added config-map envs:

RIPROXYENABLE: "ture"
RIPROXYPATH: "/redis"
RITRUSTEDORIGINS: "https://host.example.com"

However when I call the service on https://host.example.com/redis/, the bundle.js is returned on the root path https://host.example.com/static/app/bundle.e7efa0031208bf65925b.js

As image is run redislabs/redisinsight:latest

Any insight how I might overcome this?
Thank you in advance

I tried to set the RIPROXYPATH: "/redis" to RIPROXYPATH: "/redis/", nginx rewrite of the path. Non had any success.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this unanswered question. I have a similar problem to solve. I found following links that I am exploring. The solution is based on docker so currently I am looking to convert this to Kubernetes world. https://docs.redis.com/latest/ri/using-redisinsight/proxy/

It appears to just set up a proxy server to filter URLs thru, that match the subpath.

Seperately, I am also exploring URL rewrite from this sample to achieve same goals as what redis insight website advises in the above link.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/

Hope this helps. Once I have a precise answer , will be sure to post that.

UPDATE: Here is a solution - thanks to my Boss's second pair of eyes on rewrite rule to catch my missing annotation.

1. I am using Docker image latest or 1.14 from https://hub.docker.com/r/redislabs/redisinsight/tags
2. Add following to the Deployment template of your helm chart/container/spces

   ```
   env:
      - name: "RIPROXYPATH"
        value: "/rui/"
      - name: "RIPROXYENABLE"
        value: "t"
   ```
3. In your redisinsight ingress add following:
   Reference https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/
   Do not forget annotation.

   ```
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    ...
    paths:
          - path: /rui(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
   ```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am having the same issue, googled the same resources but it just doesn't work. RedisInsight tries to load it's config from /api/config instead of /redisinsight/api/config. When i configure the ingress to serve RedisInsight from root / it works.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. I did open issue on their github. Reommend up voting to get some attention. Here are links. https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/258#issuecomment-1625633617   https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/2290     https://github.com/RedisInsight/RedisInsight/issues/2289

Comment: @MarkusS. how did you figure out its loading from /api/config? I am trying to enable debug logs with no luck

Comment: I later figured out, that the UI was loading because i previously mapped the application to the root path and the browser had those frontend bundles still cached. So the frontend was still requesting it's data from the root url but the service was not listening at this endpoint (as i changed the ingress to serve the application from /redisinsight).

Comment: @MarkusS. Ok. Checkout the updated answer above. Hope that works for you too..

Comment: It kindof worked but now when i try to accept the EULA and Privacy Settings i get the error "Something went wrong submitting your preference." and the popup "Are you behind a proxy? If so, please set the RedisInsight environment variables.". The POST to /redisinsight/api/eula-screen-settings/ fails with a 404 error. /redisinsight is the subpath i configured, so this seems to be correct.

Comment: You prolly already did but just in case - did you configure the environment variables  in the solution above? Also I tried some other path than redisinsight - not that it should matter but you never know as debug log doesn't print much to decipher what may be going on under the hood

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to @user13059238's excellent answer

For me, I was getting a 403 error when trying to accept the EULA and Privacy Settings, and in the Network tab of my browser I could see the payload was:

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: Origin checking failed - https://example.com does not match any trusted origins."
}
```

So I added `RITRUSTEDORIGINS` to my environment variables, e.g.

```
env:
   - name: "RIPROXYPATH"
     value: "/rui/"
   - name: "RIPROXYENABLE"
     value: "t"
   - name: "RITRUSTEDORIGINS"
     value: "https://example.com"
```